# Safe to remove ubuntu-minimal package?

Tags: linux-mint, vim, package-management

**Intention:** I am in a process of getting rid of unused text editors.

---

**Progress:** I purged all unused ones except [`vim-tiny`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/vim-tiny), which wants to remove some other package too.

```
sudo apt-get purge vim-tiny
```

---

**Problem:** It tells me it would remove some [`ubuntu-minimal`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-minimal); package unknown to me.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-minimal* vim-tiny*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,143 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

---

**Question:** Is it safe to remove it on Linux Mint 18.1 based on Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ubuntu-minimal` is a meta package that pulls in the ubuntu base system. `vim-tiny` is a part of that package to provide an editor for the command to safely edit the sudoers file, among other things.

While it is usually safe to remove meta packages, they might be reinstalled during the next system update as part of a dependency of another package.